# In the image below,only 4 quadrants are mentioned but my intuition says there should be 8, please clarify me?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing

I am learning engineering drawing and confused on this.[image]

Comment: Why do you think there are 8 quadrants?

Comment: There are 4 *quad*rants, by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Tha author is describing First Angle Projection : accept it as it is - trying to change it will only lead to confusion.

You will soon be shown Third Angle Projection - again you will need to accept how it is done as both are used in industry - a symbol on the drawing will tell you what convention has been used.

Comment: The reason there are only four quadrants is that its describing planes in relation to a right handed rotation, not really planes as such. Atleast that was always my impression. A plane obviously has a second side as well as left sided coordinate system having separate quadrants.